# (free) tool to create word database design/shcema document from a sql server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, ms-office

Looking to document a database schema after the event.

I know red gate software have a commerical tool for this.

I'm looking for a free tool to generate a word document from a SQL Server database.

Comment: did you ever try this? Did it help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

[DbVisualizer Trial](http://dbvis.com) - try that 21 day trial